# Emmet (ex Zen Coding) - Aptana

Tags: aptana, emmet

I've been trying, through many different ways to install zen coding for aptana.

First i gone to Zen Coding project hosting, on google and found a weird zip, different from what every walkthrough describe. And following multiple walkthroughs, all of them told me to look for the aptana plugin, on zen coding githubs page. After searching for a long time, i found it, dev version. Then added as default project and stuff, but it just doesn't works and it doesn't have the LIB folder, describe in many tutorials.

Then, finally, i tried adding the official Eclipse/Aptana plugin, the weird one. As i didn't know how to install, just tried extracting to aptana plugins folder. Then, it appears on the menu scripts but when i do ctrl+e, it just crashes(the zen coding). It throws an error without many description.

I'm using Aptana studio standalone 2

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Go to:

Help -> Install new software

In the "work with" field, type this repo address: <del>http://zen-coding.ru/eclipse/updates/</del>  http://emmet.io/eclipse/updates/

Press "Add...", give it a name and press OK.

Zen coding should appear on the software list, under "uncategorised". You can install it as you'd install any other plugin.

Hope this helps.

Tested & confirmed to be working with:

- Aptana 2.0.5
- Aptana 3
- Zend Studio 8 (under Windows 7 and Ubuntu)
- Zend Studio 9 (thanks to @Patrioticcow for the info)
- Eclipse Indigo

Fails with Zend Studio 7.2, but I don't know whether it's a rule or just my bad luck.

Comment: Many thanks to you - you saved the day. Not a single word on this in Aptana docs or support, or on the zen coding site!

Comment: @Patriticcow, thank you for the information. I updated the answer to reflect it.

Comment: Zen Coding also works under Visual Studio 2012. It is available in the Web Essentials 2012 package.

Comment: I see you have already helped yourself to it :). Indeed, Zen Coding isn't developed anymore and it's called Emmet now. Thanks for the edit.